# When splitting a page in half horizontally using minipage, the second box has misaligned text

Tags: minipage

I'm trying to split an A5 page in two equal (or similar) halves using following code:

````
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\section*{Title}

\vbox{
\begin{minipage}[t][0.45\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
\subsection*{Title}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec blandit lacus. Suspendisse faucibus lorem vel ligula hendrerit feugiat. Quisque eu ullamcorper risus. Quisque vehicula magna in varius aliquam. Quisque et commodo dui, quis sodales diam. Vivamus vestibulum libero euismod risus varius, in venenatis felis congue. Mauris ante nulla, lacinia vitae libero ut, dapibus mollis ex. Integer ornare consectetur quam quis volutpat. Nullam leo ligula, bibendum vitae dui at, ultrices luctus ligula. Curabitur nec ipsum iaculis, sagittis dolor at, facilisis nunc. Morbi egestas dolor sit amet dui auctor dignissim. Mauris laoreet tempus turpis, ac aliquam lectus maximus rutrum. Nulla facilisi.
\end{minipage}

\nointerlineskip
\begin{minipage}[b][0.45\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
\subsection*{Title}     
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec blandit lacus. Suspendisse faucibus lorem vel ligula hendrerit feugiat. Quisque eu ullamcorper risus. Quisque vehicula magna in varius aliquam. Quisque et commodo dui, quis sodales diam. Vivamus vestibulum libero euismod risus varius, in venenatis felis congue. Mauris ante nulla, lacinia vitae libero ut, dapibus mollis ex. Integer ornare consectetur quam quis volutpat. Nullam leo ligula, bibendum vitae dui at, ultrices luctus ligula. Curabitur nec ipsum iaculis, sagittis dolor at, facilisis nunc. Morbi egestas dolor sit amet dui auctor dignissim. Mauris laoreet tempus turpis, ac aliquam lectus maximus rutrum. Nulla facilisi. 
\end{minipage}
}

\end{document}```
````

Above code does produce desire effect in terms of splitting the page, but the second minipage has text moved to the right:

[image]

I cannot figure out how to fix this, and would appreciate any pointers.

Here is what the log says:

> Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph

Comment: Can you post a full MWE? It's working fine for me (i.e., as intended) with KOMA-Script.

Comment: Did you try to remove the blank line between the minipages?

Comment: No. I took what he posted and stuck it between `\documentclass[a5paper]{scrartcl}
\begin{document} ... \end{document}`. And it compiled fine.

Comment: Here is MWE that produces the same result as the image above:

Comment: \documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\section*{Title}

\vbox{
\begin{minipage}[t][0.45\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
\subsection*{Title}
Text.
\end{minipage}

\nointerlineskip
\begin{minipage}[b][0.45\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
\subsection*{Title}  
Text. 
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a paragraph indentation. Normally both would be indented (and both overfull) but in the coment you added ater you showed a section heading which suppressed the first indent.

Use `\noindent\begin{minipage}`  for example.

Note a `minipage` is just positioned like a letter, so you have two paragraphs, the first paragraph after the section heading is not indented, the second one is.
As the minipage is already `\textwidth` wide and indented by `\parindent` (15pt) the line is 15pt too wide.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved it. I feel a bit ashamed for overlooking such a trivial mistake.